# What is the best way to deal with adding Drawable images programmatically?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm working on an app that deals with playing cards. Right now, I have a folder, `drawable/cards` that has dozens of files, numbered sequentially from `00.png`, that are images of the card faces.

I also have two classes, `Deck` and `Card`. `Card`s have a reference to the `Drawable` image of their face. `Deck` has a list of `Card`s that I would like to construct within a `for` loop. This all looks like,

```
public class Card{

    public Card(Drawable image) {}

};
```

```
public class Deck{

    List<Card> cardList;

    public Deck(){
        for(int i=0; i<52; ++i){
            cardList.add( new Card( ??? ) );
        }
    }

}
```

My question is, is there any way for me to generate references to the `Drawable` images of the card faces when constructing the `Card`s this way? Or do I need to find a different approach?

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried handing over the `resource id` of your drawable image instead of the whole `drawable` itself? Then you should be able to use this to draw the image in your `Card-class` using the `setImageResource()` function on your `imageView`.

Comment: It looks like I might be able to use `getResources().getIdentifier()` to implement this idea. Then all I have to do is build a string out of the sequence number to pass to `getIdentifier`.